# Single vertical lines in ggplot2 facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have a dataframe with some simple information. A sample code (A,C,T,or, G) and some counts for each sample. I also have a dataframe with some means that I want to plot as vertical lines for each code. Unfortunately, when I make the plot all means show up on all plots. Is there any way to plot one vertical line on one plot in order?

Many thanks and a simple example below

dummy data

```
sample <- c(1:100)
code <- c(rep("A", 25), rep("C", 25),rep("G", 25),rep("T", 25))
count <- sample(1:30, 100, replace=T)
df <- data.frame(sample, code, count)


vline.data <- data.frame(z = c(15, 20, 25, 30))

ggplot(df, aes(x=count))+
  geom_histogram(binwidth=.5)+
  facet_grid(. ~ code)+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = z), vline.data)+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_text(),
        axis.title.y=element_text(),
        legend.position="none")
```

Comment: Use `vline.data <- data.frame(z = c(15, 20, 25, 30), code=c("A","C","G","T"))`. That's how you associate each value with a specific facet. Instead of creating a new data frame, you can also do this on the fly using the `dplyr` package: `library(dplyr)`, then in your ggplot code: `geom_vline(aes(xintercept = z), df %>% group_by(code) %>% summarise(z=mean(count))) +`

Comment: Saw your edited post. It works now with the current code.

Comment: Just signed-in to SO for 1st time in years to say thanks 1e6 @eipi10. I spent a lot of hours banging my head against a wall of weird error messages. I had been making a separate DF (using basically your same dplyr) and for some reason that either gave an error or put all the lines in each facet as the OP here reported. Using your method gives the desired outcome. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this?:

```
sample <- c(1:100)
code <- c(rep("A", 25), rep("C", 25),rep("G", 25),rep("T", 25))
count <- sample(1:30, 100, replace=T)
df <- data.frame(sample, code, count)

library(dplyr)

vline.data <- df %>%
              group_by(code) %>%
              summarize(z = mean(count))

ggplot(df, aes(x=count))+
  geom_histogram(binwidth=.5)+
  facet_grid(. ~ code)+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = z), vline.data, colour = "red")+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_text(),
        axis.title.y=element_text(),
        legend.position="none")
```

[image]